# Two background-images, only one should repeat

Tags: css

I have a background image and a grid layout over it. Now i want that the grid layout repeats, but not the gackground-image itself. How can i do it?

```
background-image: url('/image/grid.png'), url(../images/img-bg.jpg)!important;
background-repeat: repeat;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stack multiple `background-images` by separating them with comma.

Try:

```
background: url('/image/grid.png') repeat, url(../images/img-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
```

[Read more information here.](http://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/)